# Search browsing history in Firefox on iOS

Tags: ios, firefox

Is there a way to search one’s browsing history in Firefox on iOS?  I can scroll the history, but I don’t see a search feature.

Ultimately, I’d like to search for content and selectively delete it.

Relevant: https://ilias.ca/blog/2018/10/how-to-edit-firefox-for-ios-bookmarks/

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-your-browsing-history-firefox-ios) but I don't see a search icon on my history page:

[image]